# Laravel url directing

Tags: laravel

I was making new directory in Laravel to see user profile. To do that I use

`{{ 'users/'.$post->id }}`

So it is directing to `/public/users/1`. But when user tries to check another user from the same link he is directed to '/public/users/users/1'. How can I handle that problem, any suggestions?

Comment: Needs more code to reproduce the issue. Please provide a minimal, verifiable and complete example in the question.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, provide more details, Learn to ask a question here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{ url('users/'.$post->id) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming what you are wanting is to have links that point to a specific URL based on the post ID's. As an aside, it's worth mentioning that if your intent is to generate the links for your posts model, laravel has much better ways built in to achieve this. If you have some other odd reason for needing to make your above code work, I'll go ahead and explain what's happening.

In your example, you begin the URL path with no directory indicative character, so the output of the URL will be concatenated to the end of the current URL -- the same effect as './public/users' would have. If you want the URL to be relative to the base URL and not relative to the current URL, always start your relative URL with a leading forward slash.

To make your code work, change to:

```
{{ '/public/users/'.$post->id }}
```

Comment: Which build ways you mean? Can you be more specific? I did so, because this solution was simple and worked and needed more back-end checkings against manual typing